# How to read images from memory to ImageSource in C++/WinRT (WinUI3)?

Tags: xaml, windows-runtime, winui-3, memorystream, c++-winrt

#### [1]

I want to display an image for the Image control in XAML, but this image comes from a bytes array.

What should I do? The image format may be one of JPG, BMP, or PNG.

```xml
<Image x:Name="img"/>
```

```cpp
void MainWindow::myButton_Click(IInspectable const&, RoutedEventArgs const&) {
    unsigned long long size; // iamge data size
    const unsigned char* buf; // image data

    img().Source(???); // what should I do?
}
```

#### [2]

I tried **InMemoryRandomAccessStream**, but it didn't work.

I know it's convenient to use **MemoryStream** in C#, but how to implement it in C++?

Another question is whether this method works for JPG and PNG format images as well?

```cpp
void MainWindow::myButton_Click(IInspectable const&, RoutedEventArgs const&) {
    unsigned long long size; // iamge data size
    const unsigned char* buf; // image data

    winrt::Microsoft::UI::Xaml::Media::Imaging::BitmapImage bmp;
    winrt::Windows::Storage::Streams::InMemoryRandomAccessStream stream;
    // How to read data from stream?

    bmp.SetSource(stream);
    img().Source(bmp);
}
```

#### [3]

Now I have implemented the function, but I still have two questions.

```cpp
IAsyncAction MainWindow::myButton_Click(IInspectable const&, RoutedEventArgs const&) {
    unsigned long long size; // iamge data size
    const unsigned char* buf; // image data

    winrt::Microsoft::UI::Xaml::Media::Imaging::BitmapImage bmp;
    winrt::Windows::Storage::Streams::InMemoryRandomAccessStream stream;
    winrt::Windows::Storage::Streams::DataWriter dw(st.GetOutputStreamAt(0ULL));

    dw.WriteBytes({ buf, size }); // This is very inefficient!
    co_await dw.StoreAsync();

    dw.Close();
    bmp.SetSource(stream);
    img().Source(bmp);
    stream.Close();
}
```

Firstly, I found that **DataWriter::WriteBytes()** is indeed copying data. But I think ImageSource only needs to be read from my buf, and there is no need to completely copy the entire image into the stream before reading it. Perhaps it's something like MemoryView, Am I thinking this wrong?

Secondly, where should the **Close()** of **DataWriter** and **InMemoryRandomAccessStream** be called? Do **BitmapImage** need to free up memory? There is an asynchronous function here, and I can't figure out where it should be written.

#### [4]

According to ***IInspectable***, I tried **SHCreatMemStream** and searched for a lot of information to come up with another solution. The current problem is that it is equally feasible as method **[3]**, but memory allocation still occurs.

```cpp
#include "Shlwapi.h"
#include "shcore.h"
#pragma comment(lib, "shlwapi.lib")

void MainWindow::myButton_Click(IInspectable const&, RoutedEventArgs const&) {
    unsigned long long size; // iamge data size
    const unsigned char* buf; // image data

    winrt::Microsoft::UI::Xaml::Media::Imaging::BitmapImage bmp;
    IStream* stream{ SHCreateMemStream(buf, size) }; // Copying takes a lot of time
    static const GUID guidIRandomAccessStream = { 0x905a0fe1, 0xbc53, 0x11df, { 0x8c, 0x49, 0x00, 0x1e, 0x4f, 0xc6, 0x86, 0xda } };

    winrt::Windows::Storage::Streams::IRandomAccessStream pRas{ };
    CreateRandomAccessStreamOverStream(stream, BSOS_OPTIONS::BSOS_DEFAULT, guidIRandomAccessStream, (void**)&pRas);

    bmp.SetSource(stream);
    img().Source(bmp);
}
```

Through performance testing, it was found that the time for **CreateRandomAccessStreamOverStream** is consistent, but the time consumed by **SHCreateMemStream** is proportional to the image size. It can be concluded that the process of creating a stream in **SHCreateMemStream** also involves copying memory.

I am not particularly familiar with **Stream** in Windows programming. Does the process of creating a stream necessarily involve memory copying? Can loading images from memory avoid additional overhead? And is there no structure similar to **MemoryStreamView** to replace it?

- *Another question, I know that new images must require memory storage.


  Will **BitmapImage** setting **Stream** as Source take over the memory occupied by the **Stream**?


  and will the **Image** control setting **BitmapImage** as Source take over the memory occupied by **BitmapImage**?


  If that's the case, I can accept Stream allocating new memory, otherwise it's still an efficiency problem.*

Thanks!!!!!!!

Comment: Assuming that `img()` returns an instance of the [`Image`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/uwp/api/windows.ui.xaml.controls.image) class, I wonder what `ImageSource()` is supposed to be. There is no property or function with that name on the `Image` class. Please explain which code is real and which code isn't.

Comment: Sorry, I made a mistake. It should be Source instead of ImageSource

Comment: Do you start with a chunk of memory, or is the source a file on disk? If it is the latter, you can create a [`StorageFile`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/uwp/api/windows.storage.storagefile) and get the `IRandomAccessStreamReference` implementation for free. If you have a memory block, you must (somehow) wrap that inside a stream interface. I would think that [C++/WinRT](https://aka.ms/cppwinrt) provides helpers for this, but I didn't find anything that looks immediately applicable. `winrt::array_view`, maybe, constructed from a `std::span`?

Comment: It is indeed easy to read images from files, but now I need to read them from memory blocks. The above method is feasible, but there are significant efficiency issues. I need a stream that can directly have a memory block as a view, instead of creating a stream and then copying the memory block with DataWriter and handing it over to BitmapImage for reading, which is inefficient. I have searched for C++/WinRT but have not found a solution.

Comment: I doubt that a `memcpy` will ever be the source of a *"significant efficiency issue"*, but I'm sure you can forego a copy altogether. I guess you can create an `IStream` via [`SHCreateMemStream()`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/shlwapi/nf-shlwapi-shcreatememstream) and wrap that up using [`RandomAccessStreamOverStream`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/uwp/api/windows.storage.streams.randomaccessstreamoverstream) (somehow). Alternatively, implement an [`IRandomAccessStream`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/uwp/api/windows.storage.streams.irandomaccessstream).

Comment: Thank you for your suggestion. Please refer to the revised question [4]. Although the method is feasible, replication still occurred.

Answer (score 1):

This problem has been completely solved by using Stream. As detailed in the first four issues.

As for the additional issue:

★1

use **CreatStreamOnHGlobal** instead of **SHCreatMemStream**.

Because **SHCreatMemStream** will perform another memory copy on the incoming memory block parameters during the call.

**CreatStreamOnHGlobal** does not perform memory copying after creating a stream. You can first allocate memory through **GlobalAlloc**, write the image data you need, and then call **CreatStreamOnHGlobal** without any time overhead. In addition, the second parameter of **CreatStreamOnHGlobal** can be set to true to automatically release the memory allocated by **GlobalAlloc**.

Through process memory monitoring, I found that for the same program, using **CreatStreamOnHGlobal** is twice as fast as **SHCreatMemStream** and does not result in memory leaks.

★2

The created **Stream** requires calling the Release method to reduce one reference.

**IRandomAccessStream**, as a local variable, will automatically destruct without the need for active release.

And **BitmapImage** also manages a portion of the references, which are released after leaving the scope.

Through testing the return value of the Release method on COM objects, it was found that the reference count returned to 0 after the entire program ended